# How to print a data set list vertically?

Tags: python, list

I'm working on an assignment for my intro to comp. sci. class and I have data sent that I am trying to get to print vertically, but am unable to do so.

My code:

```
def getData():
    return [

    [8,8],[2,8],[3,7],

    [3,4],[2,6],[3,5],

    [6,5],[7,3],[7,5]

]

def getLables():
    return [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

data = getData()
labels = getLables()
print('[X, Y]', data)
print('Labels:\n', labels)
```

My output:

```
[X, Y] [[8, 8], [2, 8], [3, 7], [3, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5], [6, 5], [7, 3], [7, 5]]
Labels:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Output I need:

```
[X, Y]  Lable
[8, 8]   1
[2, 8]   0
[3, 7]   0
```

and so on...

I tried using `sep='\n'` & `end='\n'` in the print statements, but it just puts adds an extra line.

Comment: Hint: you want to make a new list that looks like `[([8, 8], 1), ([2, 8], 0), ...]`, iterate over it and print the elements one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose the following:

```
def getData():
    return [[8,8],[2,8],[3,7],[3,4],[2,6],[3,5],[6,5],[7,3],[7,5]]

def getLables():
    return [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

data = getData()
labels = getLables()

print('[X, Y] Labels')
for a,b in zip(data, labels):
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either go through the two lists in parallel in a for loop or join them into a single list:

Parallel loop:

```
data   = getData()
labels = getLabels()
print("[X,Y]","Label")
for index in range(len(data)):
    print(data[index], labels[index])
```

merging the lists:

```
print("[X,Y]","Label")
for d,l in zip(getData(),getLabels()):
    print(d,l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep an index and iterate through each list equally:

```
print('[X, Y]', 'Labels:')
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    print(data[i], labels[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: You should do at least `for i in range(len(data)):` instead of a while loop with the behavior of a for loop. If  you want something Pythonic, iterate over the elements directly rather than the indexes.